# MS SQL Delete all unequal record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-delete

my problem is:
I have 2 tables (e.g. `T1` and `T2`) they both have field `Q_ID`. Table `T1` has some records in `Q_ID` column don't mach `T2`. My goal is to connect them with relation, so i want to delete all rows from `T2`, where `Q_ID` doesn't mach `Q_ID` from `T1`. I've tried to use inner join like this, but this script just deleted all records.

```
    DELETE dst FROM HRM_MVC_DEV_Test.dbo.ProjectWorkers as dst 
    INNER JOIN HRM_MVC_DEV_Test.dbo.Project as src on dst.ProjectId<>src.ProjectId
```

I am using MS SQL server 2014

Comment: BTW, can somebody explain me, why some first words in my question disappear (this issue was in my previous question too) - disappeared "Hi, guys," text from the beginning.

Comment: Because it adds noise to the question. A formal introduction, thank you, salutation, etc. is not needed in the question and only adds noise. Questions will often be edited by the community to be more clear or for formatting etc, these are often also taken into consideration and removed when encountered. Please take no offense to it, its just the way the forum was designed and how the community members prefer to interact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT, SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID INT, SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
(1,'Row 1'),(2,'Row 2'),(3,'Row 3'),(4,'Row 4');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES
(1,'Row 1'),(4,'Row 4');

DELETE FROM T1
WHERE T1.ID NOT IN(SELECT T2.ID FROM T2);

SELECT * FROM T1;
SELECT * FROM T2;
```

Comment: you may want to use not exists,nulls in t2 will lead to unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

You can also do in either ways:

```
DELETE dst 
FROM HRM_MVC_DEV_Test.dbo.ProjectWorkers AS dst 
LEFT JOIN HRM_MVC_DEV_Test.dbo.Project AS src ON src.ProjectId = dst.ProjectId
WHERE src.ProjectId IS NULL
```

--Second

```
DELETE dst 
FROM HRM_MVC_DEV_Test.dbo.ProjectWorkers AS dst 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT src.ProjectId FROM HRM_MVC_DEV_Test.dbo.Project AS src WHERE src.ProjectId = dst.ProjectId
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE
FROM HRM_MVC_DEV_Test.dbo.ProjectWorkers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HRM_MVC_DEV_Test.dbo.Project WHERE Project.ProjectId = ProjectWorkers.ProjectId)
```

You could use a NOT [EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) like the above. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

> NOT EXISTS works the opposite of EXISTS. The WHERE clause in NOT EXISTS is satisfied if no rows are returned by the subquery.